# How to show only some tics on the x axis?

Tags: gnuplot

This is :
[my x axis](http://box.jisko.net/i/1a4a7f0a.jpg)
When values are like these, there is no problem, but when values are higher all of them are too close and mixed. I would like to modify my command `set autoscale xfix` to show only half of tics. Something like:

```
0     20    40     60    80    100
```

which will show:

```
0     200    400     600    800    1000
```

with higher values and it would be clear

Anyone knows how to do this?

Comment: Could you please give some more information on what you're trying to plot? In general, you can use the `set xtics` command with the `<incr>` option, something like `set xtics 20` would put tic marks every 20 units. If you know the end of your range (which maybe you don't since you're using `autoscale`), you can use `set xtics end/5`.

Comment: I can't do what I want. For example, if autoscale shows 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900 1000 in x axis, I would like to show only 200 400 600 800 1000. In this way xtics will be more separated and numbers aren't too close. I need some way to do this, but I don't find it. I can't delete "set autoscale" because files are very different and it has to be made by program.

Comment: Why won't `set xtics 200` or `set xtics 0,200` work? If its because the data is all different, can you please post some sample data and your gnuplot script?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate `xtics` using custom math formula:

```
set xrange [0:32]
set for [i=0:5] xtics (2**i)
plot sin(x)
```

[image: exponential xtics]

in most cases you would probably be fine with regular increment:

```
set xtics autofreq 4
```

[image: manually generated xtics]

The full syntax can be found in [Gnuplot manual](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node295.html):

```
 set xtics {axis | border} {{no}mirror}
           {in | out} {scale {default | <major> {,<minor>}}}
           {{no}rotate {by <ang>}} {offset <offset> | nooffset}
           {add}
           {  autofreq
            | <incr>
            | <start>, <incr> {,<end>}
            | ({"<label>"} <pos> {<level>} {,{"<label>"}...) }
           { font "name{,<size>}" }
           { textcolor <colorspec> }
```